# Unable to enter installation 22.04 boot usb ACPI errors Laptop Legion 5 Pro

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, acpi, 22.04

Laptop: Legion 5 Pro 16ACH6H (Ryzen 5 5600H, NVIDIA RTX 3060), Discrete Graphics (similar issue with Dynamic Graphics as well, and when trying Safe Graphics in Boot USB with either Dynamic or Discrete Graphics)

When booting Ubuntu Studio 22.04 from a Bootable USB, when choosing the first option to try/install the OS, I get this error:

```
[ 0.217395] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO.PB2),
 AE_NOT FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162) 
[ 0.217407] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/ps
object-220) 
[ 0.765070] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
[ 0.874745] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO.GP17 VGA.LCD.BCH.AFNT), AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/osargs-330) 
[ 0.874910] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCIO.GP17.VGA.LCD.BCM due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/osparse-529) 
[ 3.046311] usbhid 1-2.3.2:1.2: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint


BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-ubuntu3) built-in she11 (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.


(initramfs) stdin: Invalid argument 
stdin: Invalid argument 
mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on /filesystem.squashfs failed: Invalid argument 
Can not mount /dev/loop0 (cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on /filesystem.squashfs
```

Just before the BusyBox section, the Ubuntu Studio logo flashes for less than a second and then disappears.

While I've used and relied on Linux for years at this point as a daily driver, I don't really know much about resolving issues like this. My old installation of 21.10 is still installed and working. For context, since it might be showing up in the error log, I did have trouble fixing a backlight issue with most Linux distros, but that was solved by going to an older nvidia driver. I was hoping the issue might have been solved by a newer Linux kernel, however, so I was looking forward to trying 22.04. I'm not really finding this exact issue (only similar-looking ones but with different items mentioned in the error), and I'd love to have some help on what to try next. This is my only computer, as I'm a student who has to travel often, so different hardware/getting a PC isn't a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with some help!

Problems were: Original USB didn't work so I used a different USB with different software to install the iso. The installer doesn't support my Discrete (NVIDIA) GPU, and when I used Dynamic (AMD+NVIDIA) it didn't work because I had an HDMI cable plugged in!

Solution: Switch to Dynamic (AMD+NVIDIA) GPU in the BIOS, make sure you don't have an HDMI cable plugged in, and then after like a minute you'll be in!

Bonus:Install the OS, then, to make it work properly with an Nvidia card, install the Nvidia drivers and switch back to Discrete.